# json syntax error when creating an AWS role

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, syntax, roles, amazon-iam

I’m simply copy pasting vendor documentation on creating an AWS role using JSON but getting a syntax error.

JSON:

{

"Version":"2012-10-17",

"Statement":[

```
  {

     "Effect":"Allow",

     "Action":[

        "s3:ListBucket",

        "s3:GetBucketLocation"

     ],

     "Resource":[

        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
```

] 
},

```
  {

     "Effect":"Allow",

     "Action":[

        "s3:GetObject"

     ],

     "Resource":[

        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
```

] 
}

Error received:  “An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the PutRolePolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few closing markers. A cleaned-up version is below.

Also, `<bucket-name>` needs to be **replaced** with the bucket name to which you are granting access.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you so much!